# Translating "I too can write in Latin"

Tags: translation-check, sentence-translation

I want to translate this short sentence to Latin:

> I too can write in Latin.

I mean that there are also others who know Latin, not that I can write in other languages or that I can speak Latin.

Here is my translation attempt:

> Ego quoque Latīnē scrībere possum.

Is this short sentence correct? But I'm not sure if it's correct. If anyone can help me it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just to make sure, the _too_ here intends to mean there is someone else who can write in Latin, or that you can either write in other languages or speak Latin? The word order makes me think it is the first one. Am I right?

Comment: Welcome to the site! Your translation is correct, but I think this question would be much better if you asked a *specific* question rather than "is it correct?" What parts of your translation are you unsure about?

Comment: @Rafael Yes the first one is correct. There is someone else who can write Latin.

Comment: I took the liberty to polish your question a bit. Can you add some details about what makes you doubt your own translation? It's good to know if it's something specific like word order, choice of words or correct forms, or just a general unsure feeling. I'm sure you will get answers if you edit to add some detail. Oh, and welcome to the site!

Answer (score 8):

There is nothing wrong with your translation.
The word *quoque* refers to the word preceding it.
If you write *ego quoque*, you say "also others, but me too".
Since this was the intended meaning — correct me if I am wrong! — your translation is perfect.

Placing *quoque* differently produces other meanings.
Here are three versions with overly emphatic translations to make the distinction clear:

> *Ego quoque Latīnē scrībere possum.*
> Others can write in Latin, and so can I.
>
> *Ego Latīnē quoque scrībere possum.*
> I can write in several languages, and that includes Latin, too.
>
> *Ego Latīnē scrībere quoque possum.*
> I can speak Latin, and I can also write in Latin.